# ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = "United Kingdom" does not work

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm new to sqlplus.

I tried

`'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = "United Kingdom"`

to change the currency to £. It worked once but after I changed it to

`'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = "Japan"`

and changed it back to

```
 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = "United Kingdom"
 SELECT TO_CHAR(1111, 'L9999') FROM DUAL
```

it outputs `#1111`.
How can I fix this? Looking at v$nls_parameters, this only happens only when I set it to the UK.

Answer (score 0):

[TL;DR]

- One solution may be to upgrade to Oracle 19.
- Another may be, if you are using windows command prompt, to run:

  ```
  set NLS_LANG=ENGLISH_UNITED KINGDOM.we8pc850
  ```

  before running SQL/Plus to set the code-page for displaying characters.

---

This works on Oracle's LiveSQL which is running Oracle 19c.

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = "UNITED KINGDOM";

SELECT TO_CHAR(1111, 'FML9999') FROM DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

```
TO_CHAR(1111,'FML9999')
-----------------------
£1111
```

and:

```sql
select * 
from   nls_database_parameters 
ORDER BY parameter
```

outputs:

```
PARAMETER               VALUE
----------------------- ----------------------------
NLS_CALENDAR            GREGORIAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET        AL32UTF8
NLS_COMP                BINARY
NLS_CURRENCY            $
NLS_DATE_FORMAT         DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       AMERICAN
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY        AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE            AMERICAN
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     FALSE
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION       19.0.0.0.0
NLS_SORT                BINARY
NLS_TERRITORY           AMERICA
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIME_FORMAT         HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
```

and

```sql
select * 
from   nls_session_parameters 
ORDER BY parameter
```

outputs:

```
PARAMETER               VALUE
----------------------- ----------------------------
NLS_CALENDAR            GREGORIAN
NLS_COMP                BINARY
NLS_CURRENCY            £
NLS_DATE_FORMAT         DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       AMERICAN
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       €
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY        UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_LANGUAGE            AMERICAN
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     FALSE
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_SORT                BINARY
NLS_TERRITORY           UNITED KINGDOM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIME_FORMAT         HH24.MI.SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
```

*LiveSQL [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/kusi6jnlo3edbhjfscrn51pid)*

---

However, running the same script in db<>fiddle, which is running Oracle 18c, outputs:

> ```
> | TO_CHAR(1111,'FML9999') |
> | :---------------------- |
> | #1111                   |
> ```

and the database NLS parameters are:

> ```
> PARAMETER               | VALUE                       
> :---------------------- | :---------------------------
> NLS_CALENDAR            | GREGORIAN                   
> NLS_CHARACTERSET        | AL32UTF8                    
> NLS_COMP                | BINARY                      
> NLS_CURRENCY            | $                           
> NLS_DATE_FORMAT         | DD-MON-RR                   
> NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       | AMERICAN                    
> NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       | $                           
> NLS_ISO_CURRENCY        | AMERICA                     
> NLS_LANGUAGE            | AMERICAN                    
> NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    | BYTE                        
> NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  | AL16UTF16                   
> NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     | FALSE                       
> NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  | .,                          
> NLS_RDBMS_VERSION       | 18.0.0.0.0                  
> NLS_SORT                | BINARY                      
> NLS_TERRITORY           | AMERICA                     
> NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    | DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM    
> NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT | DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
> NLS_TIME_FORMAT         | HH.MI.SSXFF AM              
> NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      | HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
> ```

and the session parameters are:

> ```
> PARAMETER               | VALUE                      
> :---------------------- | :--------------------------
> NLS_CALENDAR            | GREGORIAN                  
> NLS_COMP                | BINARY                     
> NLS_CURRENCY            | #                          
> NLS_DATE_FORMAT         | DD-MON-RR                  
> NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE       | ENGLISH                    
> NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY       | ?                          
> NLS_ISO_CURRENCY        | UNITED KINGDOM             
> NLS_LANGUAGE            | ENGLISH                    
> NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    | BYTE                       
> NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP     | FALSE                      
> NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  | .,                         
> NLS_SORT                | BINARY                     
> NLS_TERRITORY           | UNITED KINGDOM             
> NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    | DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF    
> NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT | DD-MON-RR HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
> NLS_TIME_FORMAT         | HH24.MI.SSXFF              
> NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT      | HH24.MI.SSXFF TZR
> ```

Trying various ways to get a `£` symbol as the `NLS_CURRENCY` value:

```sql
DECLARE
  TYPE StringMap IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(10) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(20);
  
  a_curr StringMap;
  v_idx  VARCHAR2(20);
  v_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  a_curr('Pound sign') := '£';
  a_curr('UNISTR(''\00A3'')') := UNISTR( '\00A3' );
  a_curr('CHR(163)') := CHR(163);
  
  v_idx := a_curr.FIRST;
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN v_idx IS NULL;
    DECLARE
      v_stmt VARCHAR2(200) := 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY = '''|| a_curr(v_idx) ||'''';
    BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( v_idx );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '  ' || v_stmt );
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_stmt;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '  ' || TO_CHAR(1111, 'FML9999' ) );
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'Error: ' || SQLERRM );
    END;
    v_idx := a_curr.NEXT(v_idx);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CHR(163)
>   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY = ''
> Error: ORA-12705: Cannot access NLS data files or invalid environment specified
> Pound sign
>   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY = '??'
>   ??1111
> UNISTR('\00A3')
>   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY = '#'
>   #1111
> ```

And none of them have set `NLS_CURRENCY` to `£`. In fact, it seems to be very difficult (impossible?) to get a `£` character to output in an Oracle db<>fiddle.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1839f3a7dbdbf43f6c3219af9e029e95)*

---

However, on a local install of Oracle 11gR2, if I run:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = "UNITED KINGDOM";
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_CURRENCY = '£';

SELECT TO_CHAR(1111, 'FML9999') FROM DUAL;
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> TO_CHAR(1111,'F
> ---------------
> £1111
> ```

Looking at this:

- The character sets are the same and there are no obvious difference in settings (and changing `NLS_LANGUAGE` to `AMERICAN` makes no difference) but its possible there is a setting that I've missed;
- It may be that the difference is in the front-end from LiveSQL to db<>fiddle (and SQL/PLUS);
- It may be in the codepage used by the operating system to display characters - you can see more details for Windows [here](https://dbamarco.wordpress.com/2015/06/25/sqlplus-character-sets-and-windows/);
- Or it may be an issue with the Oracle version and the handling of `£` is "fixed" in Oracle 19 (although since it works for me on Oracle 11g I'm not sure this is the case).